# Symfony form uppercase all fields values

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a symfony formbuilder, which is the best way to uppercase all data on forma submit?
Should i use addModelTransformer ?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, if you need uppercase string all data.

```
public function setVariable($variable)
{
    $this->variable = strtoupper($variable);

    return $this;
}
```